# Can't execute 64 bit version of my program

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, side-by-side, win64, sxs

I'm just trying to build 64 bit version of an existing program (EXE with some dependent DLLs). Since it was very easy under Linux (just recompile it), I was optimistic it could be somehow similar under Windows. Unfortunately it is not...

After starting my newly compiled EXE, I get an error message

```
The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect...
```

Tracking down the reason for it I made a SxS trace which shows following error message:

```
ERROR: Two assemblies have the same assembly name with different version.
Assembly 1: C:\Windows\WinSxS\manifests\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_fa396087175ac9ac.manifest.
Assembly 2: INFO: Manifest found at C:\Windows\WinSxS\manifests\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_fa396087175ac9ac.manifest..
```

So..what does this mean? And how can I resolve the problem? Installing the VS2010-redistributable package for x64 was not the trick, here installer complains about a newer version that is already installed...

The Manifest file mentions some X86...is this the reason? If yes: how can I find out on which X(& DLLs it still depends?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
 <assemblyIdentity version="0.64.1.0" processorArchitecture="x86" name="Controls" type="win32">   </assemblyIdentity>
  <description>wxWindows application</description>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" version="6.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="X86" publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" language="*"></assemblyIdentity>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" version="6.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" language="*"></assemblyIdentity>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"></requestedExecutionLevel>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

Comment: Show your application manifest

Comment: David Heffernan: added it to original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application manifest specifies `x86` architecture and has two entries for `comctl32`.

You should specify `x86` for your 32 bit build, and `amd64` for your 64 bit build. And you should list `comctl32` exactly once. For the dependent assembly architecture you can specify `*` if you wish, but personally I prefer to be explicit.

Comment: OK, I removed all link-references to comctl32.lib, but the problem still persists...

Comment: That's not what I said to do.

Comment: David Heffernan: All DLL's and the EXE already ARE 64 bit builds!

Comment: David Heffernan: OK, then this is a more general problem (may be of my understanding): I did not create the manifest, VS2010 is doing that automatically for me (and would overwrite it every time I rebuild the EXE). The EXE is located on an completely different location than the manifest, so I think Windows will not be able to find it. And: I plan to deploy just the exe, without any manifest...so how can this help?

Comment: The manifest is linked into your executable. I'm sure that VS would not make that manifest. It's utterly broken.